# The loop is not terminating and the program enters into the wrong conditional statement

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main() 
{
    int a, b, i;
    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);
    // Complete the code.
    for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        if (i=1)
        {
            printf("one");
        }
        else if(i=2)
        {
            printf("two");
        }
        else if(i=3)
        {
            printf("three");
        }
        .
        .
        .
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it goes till 10.
Even if a=8 the i=1 condition is executed and doesn't terminate. 
The output is oneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneone.....

Comment: Don't tag C code with C++ — or, if you consider it to be C++ code (why?), don't tag it with C too.  The answers to questions are often radically different depending on which language you're using.

Comment: Your problem is that you keep assigning in your 'conditions': `if (i = 1)` is quite different from `if (i == 1)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. Your correction made the program work as I intended. Can you please elaborate what's the deifference between i=1 and i==1?

Comment: The version `if (i = 1)` is an assignment; it sets the value of `i` to `1`, and then checks whether `1` is `0` or not.  Since it isn't `0`, the test evaluates to true.  The version with `if (i == 1)` is a comparison; it does not change the value of `i`.  Since `i` is your loop control too, you're resetting the loop control variable to `1`, then incrementing it to `2`, then checking whether it is less than or equal to `b`.  As long as `b` is at least `2`, the loop won't terminate.  If you enter `-6` and `-3` (say) for `a` and `b`, then the loop (in the code in the question) would terminate.

Comment: If you didn't get a compiler warning for this code, then something is very wrong with your compiler setup. If you did get warnings, time to start paying attention to them. If you are using a gcc-like compiler, I would strongly recommend beginners to compile with `gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic`. That way you don't have to ask the Internet about things that were already FAQ back in the 1980s :)

Answer (score 1):

To compare values, do :

```
 if (i == 1)
```

With what you did :

```
if (i = 1)
```

You assign 1 to i and the if condition check if it succeded, which is true.